# Deep link intent return unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, deep-linking

I am trying to get list of posts in categories with deep linking but it returns `Unresolved reference`

## Screenshots

`Documents`

[image: one]

`my code`

[image: two]

`Errors`

[image: three]

## Code

```
class CategoryLinkDetails : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd
    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categorylink_details, container, false)
        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.categorylinkRecycle)

        handleIntent(intent)
        return root
    }

// api code
    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
        val appLinkAction = intent.action
        val appLinkData: Uri? = intent.data

        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW == appLinkAction) {
            appLinkData?.lastPathSegment?.also { recipeId ->
                Uri.parse("content://com.my.app/categories/")
                    .buildUpon()
                    .appendPath(recipeId)
                    .build().also { appData ->
                        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
                        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity)
                        val url = "https://example.com/v1/categories/$recipeId"

                        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
                        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
                            Request.Method.GET, url,
                            Response.Listener<String> { response ->
                                val jsonArray = JSONArray(response)
                                val list: ArrayList<MyCategoryLink> = ArrayList()
                                for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
                                    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                                    list.add(parseData(jsonObject))
                                }
                                // here you will have the complete list of data in your "list" variable
                                categoriesRecycle.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
                                Log.d("my list", list.toString())
                                categoriesRecycle.adapter = MyCategoryListAdapter(list)
                            },
                            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                                //displaying the error in toast if occurrs
                                Toast.makeText(activity, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                            })
                        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                        queue.add(stringRequest)
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun parseData(jsonObject: JSONObject): MyCategoryLink {
        var listingObject = MyCategoryLink(
            jsonObject.getString("name"),
            jsonObject.getString("slug"),
            HtmlCompat.fromHtml(jsonObject.getString("body"), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT),
            jsonObject.getString("image")
        )
        return listingObject
    }
}
```

> NOTE:
>
> The only difference between my code and documentation is that I use `Fragment` because I need to show a list of posts but in docs they used `Activity`

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

**You need to handle intent data in activity class then you need to pass intent to fragment constructor**
refer below code.

```
class TestActivity :AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    handleIntent(intent)
}

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    handleIntent(intent)
}

private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
    // now from here you can add your fragment here
    var categoryDetails = CategoryDetailsFragment(intent)
    var ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    ft.add(R.id.container,categoryDetails)
}}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: so you mean i should make another file (activity)? then call that activity in my fragment?

Comment: No. you will get deep link intent in your activity which you have mentioned in androidmanifest.xml file. in activity you will get intent then you can use that intent to get data or link. after getting deeplink url you can add your fragment based on your deeplink url. hope you get this